# jq filter objects based on value of a property (not key)

Tags: jq

I have a structure like this:

```
[
  { "name":"Genus", "value": "canis" }
  { "name":"env.VAR1", "value": "dogsdrool"
  { "name":"env.VAR2", "value": "catsrule" }
]
```

I want to select the objects where the value of the name property starts with "env." (equivalently, where it matches the regex `"^env\."`)
and then concatenate the name property value with the value property value like this:

```
env.VAR1="dogsdrool"
env.VAR2="catsrule"
```

For the first part I've flailed around with select and gotten basically nowhere. It seems like this should not be hard, but it eludes me.  This is *not* filtering based on key but on a property value.

For the second part I've got this, which works well. I just can't figure out how to filter only the objects where the name property starts with `env.`

```
|"\(.name) = \(.value)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
.[] |select(.name|test("^env"))|"\(.name) = \(.value)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
echo $data | jq -r '.[]|"\(.name)=\(.value|@json)"|select(test("^env\\."))'

echo $data | jq -r '.[]|select(.name|test("^env\\."))|"\(.name)=\(.value|@json)"'
```

- You need to escape the periods in `test()` with 2 backslashes
- Use `@json` to double quote .value or `@sh` for single quote

```bash
# fyi the data you provided has missing commas and brackets
data='[{"name":"Genus","value":"canis"},{"name":"env.VAR1","value":"dogsdrool"},{"name":"env.VAR2","value":"catsrule"}]'

test1='{"name":"environment","value":"nodot"}' 

# unescaped periods will include unwanted items
echo $data $test1 | jq -rs 'flatten[]|select(.name|test("^env."))|"\(.name)=\(.value|@json)"' 
# env.VAR1="dogsdrool"
# env.VAR2="catsrule"
# environment="nodot"

# escaping with a single backslash will throw an error
echo $data | jq -rs 'flatten[]|select(.name|test("^env\."))|"\(.name)=\(.value|@json)"'
```

Comment: Since I was desigining for use in jq play, not a shell commandline, leaving things unescaped was not a problem.